# Liferay 7 Login Fragment error

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-hook, liferay-dxp

I have created login fragment for login.jsp which is working perfectly fine.

Now I need to add some code to fetch some data from custom tables so I have added XYZLocalServiceUtil call using scriptlet.

Now service call is working but problem is when I deploy fragment hook it gives following error and portlet becomes unavailable, but only for first time after deployment.

When I refresh page, next time it works properly without any error. I am not sure why it is not able to get following dependency for first time.

```
07:17:00,237 ERROR [http-nio-9080-exec-9][PortletRequestDispatcherImpl:265] Unable to dispatch request: javax.el.ELException: Provider com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl not found
07:17:00,242 ERROR [http-nio-9080-exec-9][PortletServlet:111] javax.portlet.PortletException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.el.ELException: Provider com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl not found
javax.portlet.PortletException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.el.ELException: Provider com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl not found
        at com.liferay.portlet.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:267)
        at com.liferay.portlet.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.include(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:102)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.include(MVCPortlet.java:594)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.include(MVCPortlet.java:610)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.doView(MVCPortlet.java:160)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.doDispatch(LiferayPortlet.java:303)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.doDispatch(MVCPortlet.java:497)
        at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:262)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.render(MVCPortlet.java:317)
        at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:103)
        at com.liferay.portlet.ScriptDataPortletFilter.doFilter(ScriptDataPortletFilter.java:57)
        at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:100)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:107)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.EndpointRegistration.service(EndpointRegistration.java:153)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.ResponseStateHandler.processRequest(ResponseStateHandler.java:62)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.context.DispatchTargets.doDispatch(DispatchTargets.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:48)
        at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:530)
        at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeRender(InvokerPortletImpl.java:605)
        at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.render(InvokerPortletImpl.java:391)
        at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.portlet.MonitoringInvokerPortlet.render(MonitoringInvokerPortlet.java:265)
        at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.render_005fportlet_jsp._jspService(render_005fportlet_jsp.java:1580)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectRequestDispatcher.include(DirectRequestDispatcher.java:64)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.doDispatch(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:78)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.include(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:53)
        at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl._render(PortletContainerImpl.java:707)
        at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl.render(PortletContainerImpl.java:162)
        at com.liferay.portlet.SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.render(SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.java:133)
        at com.liferay.portlet.RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.render(RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.java:133)
       ...
```

I have tried by adding following dependency in gradle file but no luck.
compile group: 'org.glassfish', name: 'javax.el', version: '3.0.0'

I am using "liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga4", If anyone faced similar issue please suggest the way to resolve it.

Thanks

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site

Comment: Thanks Olaf for pointing this, next time I will surely keep this in mind and will not post same question across sites.

Comment: could you link the questions so that the answer can be found

Comment: https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/103405707